# How can I register a Microservice Docker instance with Eureka? (AWS)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a question. I am currently in the process of deploying my microservice infrastructure via Amazon Web Service. I currently have 2 instances. 1 Eureka Discovery Service and an Api gateway. Both microservices work after I start the docker images. However, my Api Gateway is not registered with eureka. Why not?

In source code 1 you can see the logs of the Api Gateway. There are no errors. But when I start my microservices locally you can see that the Api gateway is registered in eureka.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2020-02-13 04:15:47.546  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.L.LoginJwtApiGatewayApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-13 04:15:50.031  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-02-13 04:15:50.579  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 528ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfa                                                           ces.
2020-02-13 04:15:51.162  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'bus-env' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid form                                                           at.
2020-02-13 04:15:51.915  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'bus-refresh' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid                                                            format.
2020-02-13 04:15:52.096  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a v                                                           alid format.
2020-02-13 04:15:52.174  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'hystrix.stream' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a val                                                           id format.
2020-02-13 04:15:52.902  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=55afe708-ad15-310b-9a37-2661146187a0
2020-02-13 04:15:53.825  INFO 1 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default Pu                                                           blishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2020-02-13 04:15:53.837  INFO 1 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default T                                                           hreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2020-02-13 04:15:53.856  INFO 1 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. The                                                           refore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2020-02-13 04:15:54.235  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfig                                                           uration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example                                                           : not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-02-13 04:15:54.783  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.suppor                                                           t.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-02-13 04:15:54.793  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integra                                                           tion.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-02-13 04:15:54.892  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration'                                                            of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for                                                            auto-proxying)
2020-02-13 04:15:55.897  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8800 (http)
2020-02-13 04:15:55.934  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-02-13 04:15:55.934  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-02-13 04:15:56.111  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-02-13 04:15:56.112  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8451 ms
2020-02-13 04:15:56.454  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2020-02-13 04:15:56.458  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.                                                           configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2020-02-13 04:15:56.542  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.con                                                           fig.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@c94fd30
2020-02-13 04:15:56.757  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be                                                            performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-02-13 04:15:57.426  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-02-13 04:15:57.660  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
2020-02-13 04:15:58.091  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-02-13 04:15:58.437  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-02-13 04:15:59.512  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-02-13 04:15:59.563  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

```
 docker run -d -e "eureka.client.serviceUrl.defauftZone=http://ec2-18-185-58-36.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8762/" -e "server.port=8800" -p 8800:8800 -e "eureka.instance.ip-address=3.134.175.64" -e "eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true" doncarlito/sendmessage
```

In source code 2 you can see how I do my instance with my docker container. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?